# What does it mean (non) convex "constraint"?

Tags: classification, svm, optimization

I was referring [SVM section](http://cs229.stanford.edu/notes2020fall/notes2020fall/cs229-notes3.pdf) of Andrew Ng's course notes for Stanford CS229 Machine Learning course. On page 16, he says:

> SVM optimization problem can be given as follows:
> $$\begin{align} 
> \max_{\gamma,w,b}\gamma \\
> s.t. & \quad  y^{(i)}(w^Tx+b) \geq\gamma, \quad i=1,...,n \\
> & \quad \Vert w \Vert =1. \\
> \end{align}
> $$
> But the "$\Vert w \Vert$" constraint is a nasty (non-convex) one, ...

I am unable to understand why the constraint $\Vert w \Vert$ is non-convex.

PS: I understand the basic definition of convex "function" and I have not delved any deep in optimization theory.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can notice that the points which are satisfying the constraint are the surface of a norm-ball. Hence they don't form a convex set.

Also, consider ∥x∥=1 and ∥-x∥=1. You can easily observe that (1/2)(x+(−x)) has 0 norm. So, it is not closed under convex combination.

Comment: am really not able to get it. I tried understanding what "$p$-norm ball" from here: [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/520015/739971), [2](https://www.geogebra.org/m/pyxfvyyk). But what do you mean by "norm ball" (without $p$)? Can you explain "every sentence" a bit in more detail? I guess I lack the background concepts to understand. For example, I didn't get why "points satisfying the constraint are the surface of a norm-ball".